# what is the fastest function in RDD spark

Tags: function, apache-spark, rdd

I'm implementing `GroupBy` function and it is "transformations" operation.

I need that the my GroupBy function must be computed immediately, so I've found out a solution that calling another "action" likes `first()` or `count()` operation after GroupBy then it will be computed.

The running time of `GroupBy` is equal its + the `action` operation, and thus I need a fastest function to minimum total running time!!

thanks!

Comment: What do you do with the results of the `groupBy` if you only need to materialize it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are doing this for a performance testing kind of thing.So if i am right it don't really matter what your action returns,you just need the transformation(groupby) to be executed.
I think `first()` is fastest rdd action i can think of.

Another approach is you can find the time taken for the **transformation**(group by) **alone** in the webui of spark.So you can use any rdd action you wish!